# This error message is killing me: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected"

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax, alias

Here's the section of the query that's throwing the error (I had help getting to this, I'm a newbie):

```
select name 
from sc_item_option_mtom mtom
    join sc_item_option vars on vars.sys_id = mtom.sc_item_option
    join sys_user u on u.sys_id = value 
where mtom.request_item = req.sys_id 
    and (dv_item_option_new = 'SID ID Name' 
    and vars.order = 1) as [SID Name Application]
```

If I take out the `and vars.order = 1` , it works.

I've tried putting parentheses in all sorts of different places, changing the order of the conditions, wrapping it all in EXIST and adding '' around the 1 (but the 1 is an integer in the data).

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Adding a language or database tag may help your question get more attention from interested people. Looks like a type of SQL?

Comment: you're missing a second parentheses after that part: `and vars.order = 1))`. Or at least put it before the `AS`

Comment: Actually you don;t need parentheses around that second clause, so a cleaner fix would be: `where mtom.request_item = req.sys_id and dv_item_option_new = 'SID ID Name' and vars.order = 1) `

Comment: And you might need to qualify the column name in `vars.order` so that the engine knows you're not using `ORDER` as a keyword. (Hence the best practice of not using keywords as object names.)

Comment: Your parenthesis are kind of off, I think it's evaluating the alias "as [SID Name Application] " as a condition.

Comment: Thanks, @DStanley. I tried that but still get the error message.

Comment: Hi @EricBrandt, how would I qualify that column? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrissyScott, that will depend on the database engine you're using. [Why Should I Tag My RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms/). If this is SQL Server, wrap it in square brackets; `vars.[order]`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. A combination of things got me squared away: () around dv_item_option_new and =1, and adding [ ] around order.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select name from sc_item_option_mtom mtom join sc_item_option 
vars on vars.sys_id = mtom.sc_item_option 
join sys_user 
u on u.sys_id = value where mtom.request_item = req.sys_id and (dv_item_option_new = 
'SID ID Name' and vars.[order] = 1)) as [SID Name]
```

Comment: You should add some explanation in your answer with the code